# sqlite3 in data receive python communication

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

this is a simple chat code in python programming.I want to receive an increasingly aware of and store the ip, host, and message. But as it is, it only records once and not always? resolve like this?
(I use SQLITE3)

```
while true:
    data = conn.recv (1024)
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE amo(IP INT, data TEXT)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO amo VALUES(?,?)", (HOST, data))
```

Comment: Why are you recreating the table over and over in the `while` loop?

Comment: This is my problem , i neddo a while true to repeat a data recieved of my client, and i need to saver a ip address, data and time each message. But is receating table, this is a problem

Comment: But why are you running `CREATE TABLE` in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Duarte, you have very nearly answered your own question, you are re-creating the table with each loop. Separate out your logic:

```
# establish you database connection and create the table, if it does not already exist
... (create your db connection here) ...
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS amo(IP INT, data TEXT)")

# open your chat connection, and store the data
while True:
    ... (chat data) ...
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO amo({},{})".format(HOST, data))
```

You will only have to create the table once, then it will be in the sqlite3 db, you can establish a connection to the db at the start of our script, and manipulate the data in the db to your heart's content after that.

Comment: Thanks, but is not work,in each while is not save a host, and the data (information of each client). This is not save anything

Comment: this is not work , erro in ({},{})" and in .format(HOST, data))